# How do I get all the shader constants (uniforms) from a ID3DXEffect?

Tags: c++, graphics, 3d, directx

I'm creating an effect using

```
hr = D3DXCreateEffectFromFile( g_D3D_Device, 
        shaderPath.c_str(),
        macros, 
        NULL, 
        0, 
        NULL, 
        &pEffect, 
        &pBufferErrors );
```

I would like to get all the uniforms that this shader is using. In OpenGL I used glGetActiveUniform and glGetUniformLocation to get constant's size, type, name etc. Is there a D3DX9 equivalent function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
D3DXHANDLE handle = m_pEffect->GetParameterByName( NULL, "Uniform Name" );
if ( handle != NULL )
{
    D3DXPARAMETER_DESC desc;
    if ( SUCCEEDED( m_pEffect->GetParameterDesc( handle, &desc ) ) )
    {
        // You now have pretty much all the details about the parameter there are in "desc".
    }
}
```

You can also iterate through each parameter by doing the following:

```
UINT index = 0;
while( 1 )
{
    D3DXHANDLE handle = m_pEffect->GetParameter( NULL, index );
    if ( handle == NULL )
        break;

    // Get parameter desc as above.
    index++;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Using

> m_pEffect->GetParameter( NULL, index );

in while (1) cycle will result in

> D3DX: ID3DXEffect::GetParameter: Invalid index

warning.

So we can use the D3DXEFFECT_DESC struct to find how many parameters an Effect has.

Something like this:

```
D3DXEFFECT_DESC fx_desc;
g_pEffect->GetDesc(&fx_desc);

for (UINT index=0;index<=fx_desc.Parameters;index++)
{
    D3DXHANDLE handle = g_pEffect->GetParameter( NULL, index );
    if ( handle == NULL )
        break;

    D3DXPARAMETER_DESC param_desc;
    if ( S_OK == ( g_pEffect->GetParameterDesc( handle, &param_desc ) ) )
    {
        //check the details about the parameter in param_desc
    }
}
```